# Identify why Nagios call is taking longer than identical root call

Tags: linux, nagios, esx

I'm monitoring ESX.

When I call the command being root, I get the answer in less than 2 seconds. When I call it from the Nagios user, it takes almost 4 minutes to get the same answer.

How can I determine why the Nagios user call is taking longer to complete this command?

Comment: strace, set -x on the script as on superuser…

Comment: Is it a remote command (ssh)?  If so, test that from the command line as the nagios user as well.